# Complexity of a given function

Tags: function, complexity-theory, big-o

When I analyzed the complexity of the code segment below, I found that it is *O(n/2)*. But while searching the internet I discovered that it is probably *O(n)*. I'd like to know who's correct.

```
void function(int n) {
    int i = 1, k = 100;
    while (i < n) {
        k++;
        i += 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

What is the point of the variable k in the above method?  Regardless big-O notation talks about the behavior in the limit (as the value of n approaches infinity).  As such, big-O notation is agnostic to BOTH scaling factors and constants.  Which is to say, for any constant "c" and scaling factor "s"

O(f(n)) is equivalent to O(s*f(n) + c)

In your case f(n) = n, s = 1/2, and c = 0. So...

O(n) = O(n/2)

Answer (score 6):

O(n) is the same as O(n/2)

The idea of big-O notation is to understand how fast an algorithm will run as you give it a larger input.  So, for example, if you double the size of your input, will the program take twice as long or will it take 4 times as long.

Since both n and n/2 behave identically as you vary the value of N (i.e. if you increase N by a factor of 10, both N itself and N/2 scale identically).

Answer (score 4):

*O(n/2) = O(0.5n) = O(n)*. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) for more on this.

If *f* is *O(g)*, then there exist some *c* and *n* such that for all *x > n*, *|f(x)| <= c * |g(x)|*. That is, from input *n* onwards, *c * g(x)* dominates *f(x)*.

It follows that *O(n/2) = O(n)*, because,

- If *f(x) = x/2* and *g(x) = x*, then we set *c = 0.5* and *n = 0*.
- If *f(x) = x* and *g(x) = x/2*, then we set *c = 2* and *n = 0*.

Note that there are infinitely many values for *c* and *n* that you can use to prove this. (In the above I minimized them, but that is not necessary.)